# Kotlin: vararg of varargs in constructor

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am trying to implement the Filter class. My first version was the one on this question: [Kotlin vararg of A to vararg of B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061843/kotlin-vararg-of-a-to-vararg-of-b/54061953#54061953)

At that point I had not noticed the recursivity when constructing with a predicate, so I am looking for another way of implementing that.

I've changed it to this class declaration: `class Filter<in T>(vararg val predicates: (T) -> Boolean)`

I am trying to get this other constructor to work:

```
constructor(vararg filters: Filter<T>) : this(/* do something */)
```

I don't know how to map a vararg of filters (which contain a vararg of predicates) into a vararg of predicates that have all the predicates in each filter, especially considering that I cannot invoke any function in the filter class because it has not been initialized at that point.

Also, is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to get (a class that can be created with both an array of predicates or an array of instances of the class itself)?

Comment: You are probably missing the `*` (spread) operator from before the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
typealias Predicate<T> = (T) -> Boolean

class Filter<T> {
    private val pred: MutableList<Predicate<T>> = mutableListOf()

    constructor(vararg val predicates: Predicate<T>) {
        predicates.forEach { pred.add(it) }
    }

    constructor(vararg filters: Filter<T>) {
        filters.forEach { pred.addAll(it.pred) }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f1 = Filter<String>({true}, {true})
    val f2 = Filter<String>(f1, f1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought about having a separate variable from the constructor param.
Also, thanks for showing me the use of typealias :D